# python loop only runs once

Tags: python, loops

why does the following function only runs once a sends only one set of data. I thought for each must mean for each value in the data set.

```
data_checkpoint_size = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.size')
data_checkpoint_length = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.length')
data_checkpoint_pause = cclient.samples.list(meter_name ='checkpoint.pause')


def counterVolume(data_checkpoint_size, data_checkpoint_length, data_checkpoint_pause):
  for each in data_checkpoint_size:
    d = each.counter_volume
  for each in data_checkpoint_length:
    e = each.counter_volume
  for each in data_checkpoint_pause:
    f = each.counter_volume
  pubnub.publish(channel='channel', message= {'checkpoint_size': d, 'checkpoint_length': e, 'checkpoint_pause': f})

counterVolume(data_checkpoint_size, data_checkpoint_length, data_checkpoint_pause)
```

And I only get following as result instead of series of data. checkpoint_size, checkpoint_length and checkpoint_pause are three different meters, these are three different data streams

```
{
  checkpoint_length: 75,
  checkpoint_size: 5000,
  checkpoint_pause: 50
}
```

Comment: Well, for one thing, we need to see how you're calling it.

Comment: Are you talking about `pubnub.publish` being only called once? It *will* get called once, because it's *outside* the loop.

Comment: Your d, e, and f are re-assigned through the for loop.

Comment: @Imo Do you want to run `pubnub.publish` for each combination of values in the 3 lists , or like once for each 0th index in the list, second time for all 1st index, etc??

Comment: @AnandSKumar yes I would like to have a series of data

Comment: series of data means? Can you show with example , if the below answers have not already fixed your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @ismailsunni said, your variables are reassigned. This makes the assumption that all data is of the same length, but it should work:

```
def counterVolume(data_checkpoint_size, data_checkpoint_length, data_checkpoint_pause):
    for i, size in enumerate(data_checkpoint_size):
        length = data_checkpoint_length[i]
        pause = data_checkpoint_pause[i]
        message = {
            'checkpoint_size': size .counter_volume,
            'checkpoint_length': length.counter_volume,
            'checkpoint_pause': pause.counter_volume,
        }
        pubnub.publish(channel='channel', message=message)
```

I'd test to make sure they're all the same length first and raise a specific exception (so it's easier to debug):

```
size_len = len(data_checkpoint_size)
length_len = len(data_checkpoint_length)
pause_len = len(data_checkpoint_pause)

if size_len != length_len or length_len != pause_len:
    raise Exception('Custom exception message.')
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding d, e, and f each time `each.counter_volume` is called. If you wish to end up with lots of collections of returned data, you'll need something like this:

```
for i in range(data_checkpoint_size):
    d = data_checkpoint_size[i].counter_volume
    e = data_checkpoint_length[i].counter_volume
    f = data_checkpoint_pause[i].counter_volume
    pubnub.publish(channel='channel', message= {'checkpoint_size': d, 'checkpoint_length': e, 'checkpoint_pause': f})
```

It is worth noting that this assumes that all your data sets are of equal length. For a more in depth answer, you will need to provide a more in depth question regarding what it is that you are trying to achieve.